# Can't add 2 same modules on Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am a beginner programmer so I do not master certain parts very well.
I developed a joomla module that allows you to display an accordion menu according to the level you entered in the admin interface for my company's website. My module is made of a php file containing  also the style part and the script (the links to the Jquery scripts) and an XML file.

My problem is that as soon as I try to add on the same page 2 articles using the same module the page just crash and I don't know why, is there any kind soul that could help me to figure out what is the problem please ?
(also it's my first time using Stack Overflow I'm sorry if I am using it in a wrong way)

Here is my code (without the database connexion and the whole path to the script) :

```
    <?php 

//space dedicated to the connexion to the database





$idMod=$module->id; //Idendifiant du module a intéger en cas de script dans le nom des paramètres
$id.$idMod=$params->get('base'); //We retrieve the parameters


  //We check to connexion
if($mysqli->connect_error){
      die('Erreur : ' .$conn->connect_error);
  }


function HasChildAccordion($mysqli, $Num, $idModule){  //lets you know if there are children for the associated menu
    $Nbenfant.$idMod=0;
    $Enfant.$idMod= "SELECT id FROM sgc_menu WHERE parent_id=$Num AND published=1";
    $exec=mysqli_query($mysqli, $Enfant.$idMod);
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($exec, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $Nbenfant.$idMod= $Nbenfant.$idMod+1;
    }
    $Nbenfants.$idMod=$Nbenfant.$idMod;
   return $Nbenfants.$idMod;

}


function getChildAccordion($mysqli, $bla, $idModule){  //Recursive function to display menu names and retrieve submenus
    
    $query.$idMod="SELECT link, title, level, parent_id, id FROM sgc_menu WHERE id=$bla AND published=1";
    $exec=mysqli_query($mysqli, $query.$idMod);
     
    
    while ($TOTO = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {  
        
  $test=HasChildAccordion($mysqli, $TOTO['id'], $idMod);
    
    if ( $test!=0){
        
        //echo '<a class="myNav-link ui-accordion-trigger'.$idMod.'" href="'.$TOTO['link'].'">'.$TOTO['title'].'</a>';
       echo '<a class="myNav-link ui-accordion-trigger" href="'.$TOTO['link'].'">'.$TOTO['title'].'</a>';
       // echo '<div class="myNav-content ui-accordion-content'.$idMod.'">' ;
        echo '<div class="myNav-content ui-accordion-content">' ;
        
        $query2="SELECT id, title, level, parent_id, link FROM sgc_menu WHERE parent_id=$bla AND published=1";//On récupères les enfants 
        $exec2=mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2);
        while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($exec2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ // For every children we apply the function getChildAccordion;        
           // echo '<div class="subNav ui-accordion'.$idMod.'">';
                echo '<div class="subNav ui-accordion">';
            getChildAccordion($mysqli, $result['id'], $idMod); //we display children's children 
            echo '</div>' ; 
        } 
        echo '</div>' ;   
         
    } else {
        //echo '<div class="myNav-item ui-accordion-item'.$idMod.'">'; 
        echo '<div class="myNav-item ui-accordion-item">'; 
        echo '<a class="clicable" href="'.$TOTO['link'].'">'.$TOTO['title'].'</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    }
     
    //  $Nbenfant=0;
}


//echo '<div class="myNav ui-accordion'.$idMod.'">';
echo '<div class="myNav ui-accordion">';
getChildAccordion($mysqli, $id.$idMod, $idMod);  //the function is called with the menu chosen in the configuration of the module
echo '</div>';

?>


<script src="http://.../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://.../jquery.simpleAccordion.min.js"></script>


<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ui-accordion').simpleAccordion ({
    item :'.ui-accordion-item',
    trigger :'.ui-accordion-trigger',
    content :'.ui-accordion-content',
    active :'active',
    autoclose:true,
    multiple :true,
    speed:500 });
}); 
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('.SubNav').simpleAccordion ({
    trigger :'.subui-accordion-trigger',
    content :'.subui-accordion-content',
    active:'active',
    autoclose:true,
    multiple:true,
    speed:1000});
}); 
</script>

//

<style>
<?php

    $colorbg=$params->get('colorbg');
    $colortext=$params->get('colortext');
    $colorHover=$params->get('colorHover');
    $FontSize=$params->get('FontSize');
    $colortextClickable=$params->get('colortextClickable');
    ?>


.myNav {
    position: static; 
    display:block; 
    background-color: <?php echo $colorbg ; ?>;    
    padding:2% 2% 2% 2%; 
    margin: 2% 2% 2% 5%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #1c4281;
    margin: 5px 22px 18px 22px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(28, 66, 129, 0.75);
    font-family: Kepler_296;
    }
.myNav a{
    
    position : static; 
    display:inline; 
    color:<?php echo $colortext ; ?>;
    font-family: Kepler_296;
    }
.myNav-item:not(:first-child) { 
    border-top:1px solid #fff; 
    }
.myNav-link { 
    position:static;
    display:block;  
    
    } 
.myNav-content { 
    position:static;
    display:block; 
    padding:2% 2% 2% 2%; 
    margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%; 
    
    } 
    
.subNav{
justify-content:space-around;
    }
    
.ui-accordion-content, .subui-accordion-content{ display:none; }
    
    
    
    
.active > .ui-accordion-content, .active> .subui-accordion-content { 
    display:block;
    }   
  
a.clicable {       
    color:<?php echo $colortextClickable ; ?>;
    font-family: Kepler_296;
    font-size: <?php echo $FontSize ; ?>px;
    }
    
a.clicable:hover{
        color:<?php echo $colorHover ; ?>;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
            
    
.ui-accordion-trigger{
    font-size: <?php echo $FontSize ; ?>px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: static;
    display: inline;
    }

    
.ui-accordion-trigger::after { 
    margin: -15px 0px 0px 2px;
    content:'\1F892'; 
    position:static;
    display: inline;
    float:right;
    top:50%;
    font-size: 40px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }        
.active> .ui-accordion-trigger::after{
margin: -15px 0px 0px 20px;
    position: static;
    display: inline;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);  
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    }         
    
</style>
```

I thought the problem came from a variable but I sincerly have no idea

Comment: Custom Joomla extensions should not be creating their own mysqli connection variable -- you should be using Joomla's database class connection variable.  Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot debug the whole thing.
But here's a couple of things I noticed:

```
$query.$idMod =
```

is a funny way to put the sql into $idMod. And it does nothing to $query. Also, it is beyond confusing.

What you wanted to achieve is most likely to declare a different variable name for your query for each instance of the module.
This would be achieved with:

```
${'query'.$idMod} =
```

but you don't need it. Most likely, the cause for the module content repeating is the cache, try disabling it.

Finally, you might want to look into css variables, the stylesheet you pasted would benefit from using them.

Comment: Thank you very much for you advice, it looks way neater like that

We figured out what was the problem, we couldn't create the same function twice so We just had to add a condition to see if the function arleady existed 